# JavaScript date with offset capability and a specific format 'Sunday, 31 Oct 2019'

Tags: javascript, regex, date, date-format

I've not been able to find a solution for a specific date format I want such as 
*Sunday, 31 Oct, 2019*. I also require an offset value for the date.

The closest I could get was *Sun 31 Oct 2019*. 
I need to be able to offset the date with a number entered by a user. 
With the script I have below, on certain dates, the day/name returns "undefined" although the other date items return as correct.

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
return date;}

date = new Date();
offset = effect("Slider Control")("Slider");

dayOffset = offset%7;

myDate = (date.addDays(offset));

dateString = String(myDate);

myMonth = dateString.split(/\s+/).slice(1,3).join(' ');

d = new Date();
days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
myDay = days[d.getDay()+dayOffset];

myDay + ", " + myMonth
```

What am I missing? Could you please advise me?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I did use this - 
dayOffset = offset%7

Do take note that "offset" is the user input value to offset from today's date. .

Comment: Given you've already added the offset to *myDate*, why not `myDay = days[myDate.getDay()]`. Also, `new Date(this.valueOf())` can be simply `new Date(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
myDay = days[d.getDay()+dayOffset];
```

can easily result in accessing beyond the end of the array, in which case you get the value `undefined`. Consider if it's Friday (day 5) and you add 3 to it. 5 + 3 = 8, but your array's indexes only go up to 6.

To wrap around, use `% days.length` (or `% 7` if you want to hardcode it; I wouldn't):

```
myDay = days[(d.getDay() + dayOffset) % days.length];
```

8 % 7 is 1, Monday, which is indeed Friday plus three.

Comment: OK! Great. It works!!! I stuck in your code and all is good now. Many thanks for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found a more robust & elegant code -

`enter code here`Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
`enter code here`var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
`enter code here`date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
`enter code here`return date;}
`enter code here`date = new Date();
`enter code here`offset = 5;
`enter code here`myDate = (date.addDays(offset));
`enter code here`options = { weekday: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
`enter code here`(myDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options))

I sorta extrapolated info from this answer - 
[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?rq=1)